# Recover Headerless Encrypted NTFS File Deleted in Ubuntu

Tags: files, encryption, data-recovery, ntfs, undelete

My girlfriend had shift-deleted a "Folder Lock" encrypted locker file from my NTFS external drive using her Ubuntu PC. That file has <.flka> extension with NO known file signature. As far as I observed, no Windows application can recover this type of file if deleted in Ubuntu, unless otherwise it has been deleted using Windows OS. I already tried NTFSUndelete, TestDisk and Photorec using Ubuntu Live CD but none of them seems to work. I considered using Scalpel or Foremost but the lack of File Header and fragmentation is the problem since I can see almost all parts of the file throughout the drive by Hex editor. Nothing has been written to the drive after deletion. Please somebody help me solve this scenario.

Comment: I don't know anything about it, but you can try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Works on Windows (depending on version) or Ubuntu. Says it supports NTFS but does not say anything about encryption.

Comment: If what you say is true, then it's gone.

Comment: a bit off-topic, but if you can see the file by hex editor, you might want to [manually undelete](http://html5.litten.com/windows-file-recovery-series-part-5-manually-recover-a-deleted-file-from-an-ntfs-file-system/) the file...

Comment: I find it hard to do manual carving because the header is composed of unsearchable pseudo-random 512 bytes with a pattern of another random sequence of bytes several offset with each other. Searchable ones are just parts of encrypted contents that can't be decrypted without completing those random bytes header. I'm really willing to give reward to anybody who can enlighten me.

Comment: If NTFSUndelete, TestDisk, Photorec *and* manual undelete do not work, I'd say I have to agree with @psusi and the file is lost.  With encrypted files, back-ups become even more important...  Sorry to be of no further help

Comment: My hope of recovery is the fact that no further data had been written to the drive after deletion and as well as the presence of several encrypted file fragments still intact throughout the disk. I wish there's a tool or a right way to assemble or carve this 50GB size of fragmented file which is mixed with terabytes of data.